# Getting "[TypeError]: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')`" while using axios post in next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js, axios

I am getting an error while using next.js app dir and trying to send a post request with axios.

```
  const submitHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const {data} = await axios.post('/api/register', {
        name, 
        email, 
        password,
      });
      console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

the error (part of it):

```
error - Error [TypeError]: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/objectid.js:15:36)
    at (sc_server)/./node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/objectid.js (/Users/yakovtzur/Documents/Coding/Development/next_13_authjs/.next/server/app/api/register/route.js:2870:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/yakovtzur/Documents/Coding/Development/next_13_authjs/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(sc_server)/./node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:7:18)
```

Comment: can you please add more details ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If using mongoose 7, put serverComponentsExternalPackages option in next.config.js:

```js
/** @type {import("next").NextConfig} */
module.exports = {
    experimental: { appDir: true, serverComponentsExternalPackages: ["mongoose"] },
    webpack(config) {
        config.experiments = { ...config.experiments, topLevelAwait: true };
        return config;
    }
};
```